# Using noise as an alpha for noise (bump) texture

Tags: transparency

I am trying to figure out how to use noise node to control the visibility of another noise node that I am using for bump. (in effort to break up the bump on the surface)
I would like to use the left highlighted noise transparency to control the highlighted noise node in the middle. but cant for the life of me figure out how to go about it. somebody help? is it super simple and should I feel stupid?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a *Mix Shader* node to mix your 2 *Noise Texture* nodes, shaders determine the appearance of the surface (emissive, transparent, glassy, etc) and are placed just before the *Output*, instead mix your 2 textures into a *Color > Mix Color* that you switch for example to *Screen* mode, which will make the white spots of the second texture appear through the black spots of the first texture, example, with factor set to 0:

[image]

Then factor to 1:

[image]

Comment: thanks a bunch works great